# Does autorelease hide leaks in Instruments?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Here is a scenario that appears to trick Leaks:

1. Generate UIView *v from a Nib or using alloc/init.
2. Allocate, init, and autorelease a bunch more views e.g. UIButton, and attach them to the UIView as subviews.
3. Release the view v.

That's it. The subviews are not released, but Leaks will not see them either.

Has anyone else seen this?

Note: The solution to this problem is to removeFromSuperview anything attached to v.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that they aren't released?

It sounds like your retains and releases are balanced, so they should be released correctly. What may be confusing you is that because they are autoreleased, they won't be released right away but will instead be released 1/60th second later when the autorelease pool is flushed.

In case it helps clarify things: Views automatically retain subviews when they are added, and release them when they are themselves released (just like adding items to an array).

Comment: The subviews are eventually released, but it takes forever and memory warnings happen before that.

Comment: Yes, exactly like an array. In fact `subviews` is an array. You wouldn't add an `NSString` to an `NSMutableArray` and then call `autorelease` you would just call `release`.

Comment: I guess my problem that they aren't released *soon enough* for that release to be useful in preventing memory warnings. Not sure why that is. Thus my solution is, create the subviews, add them to v, then release them rather than autoreleasing.

Comment: What, wait. If you're getting memory warnings you are doing something wrong. Could you show us how you are instantiating the views?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on the [memory guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

You have done your part of the memory management by autoreleasing the UIViews you created, and you have transferred the ownership of them to UIView v.

**Edit**

After reading your comments it seems like they are actually not getting released, which could be to a circular reference. Are you sure nothing else is retaining the view? How are you instantiating them?